# Can you do this level of simulation in Blender?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I've been trying to do some simulations on blender like this:
https://www.instagram.com/p/CvxTvogNuGI/
[image]

Does anyone knows if it's possible on Blender or only on C4D?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried a *Cloth* simulation? You have even added the relevant tags to your question. So, what doesn't work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Blunder I feel it gets super heavy and glitchy even with low poly meshes

Comment: I would suggest you give Houdini Apprentice a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing- floppy overlapping objects using ***soft bodies*** with plushy,carpet, or felt textures on the objects. We need a little space between them so they don't fall too quickly.

<kbd>ctrl+J</kbd>
to ***join all the soft body objects*** that fall and collide with each other.   Check the origin box in `Options` and make sure that the origin is at the bottom of all the objects, and after  <kbd>ctrl+A</kbd> make sure scale is applied.
After joining all the ojects make sure that ***self collision*** is turned on.

The only other thing is to make the surface they will collide with a collision object.

I achieved reasonable success with these settings.

[image]

**Reasoning**

Objects have unrealistically high mass and have extremely high friction to stop them sliding.

Objects have low push/pull, to stop them from jiggling.

Objects have high damping, to stop them from springing.

Objects are plastic and very bendy.

We want more steps in the Solver to get them to check for collisions frequently.

Here are my results:

[image]

[image]